# Transactions with drop box style integration pattern

Tags: database, transactions, insert, filesystems, distributed

I'm currently facing a problem trying to design a robust solution using a drop box style integration pattern.  Files arrive in a folder on a filesystem and I have to put the contents into a Oracle database.  The problem is that the transaction completes and then the file is moved to another folder to indicate processing is complete.  Suppose the process were killed in between the time of the commit and the moving of the file.  When the process is restarted the file contents would be inserted into the database again resulting in duplicate data.  I feel there are couple of approaches to make a robust solution, but I'm not sure which one to choose.  I read Pat Helland's paper  [Life beyond Distributed Transactions: an Apostate's Opinion](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~cs223/papers/cidr07p15.pdf), but now I am facing practical implementation issues.

1. I could make the insertion process idempotent somehow.  In other words a second insert attempt would fail because the data would already be in database.  Unfortunately, the data has no unique identifier other than one I would give it, so I would have to start the insertion process incorporating the identifier as part of the file name and renaming the file as soon as it arrives on the system.  The insertion process would then use the key as  part of the primary key when inserts are attempted.
2. I could do some sort of distributed transaction using the filesystem and the database. I could tie the file move to the same transaction as the database commit.  I am using Java and I am aware of distributed transactions (XAResource), but I have never used them.  This solution might include using [JBoss Transactional File I/O](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/fileio), although there are precious few alternatives.  XADisk is another off the shelf library that might do similar.
3. I could use some other alternative I have not thought of.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In case you feel like going with XA, you can give [XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) a try. I have been an active part of the XADisk project, and there are some real life projects which have solved the problem of file<->database consistency, similar to what you wrote, using XADisk.

I believe you would find XA simple, atleast from the application developer perspective who don't have to write a transaction-manager for XA.

Hope that helps.

Nitin (@XADisk)